# XML doesn't display into HTML (Using Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web, rss

Well, I imagine this will be easy but can't solve it... 
I'm trying to display a basic RSS into a HMTL code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
            {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
        else
            {// code for IE6, IE5
            var xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }

xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.nacion.com/Generales/RSS/EdicionRss.aspx?section=deportes",false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML; 

document.write("<table border='1'>");
var markup = "<table border='1'>";
var x=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("item");
for (i=0;i<x.length;i++)
{ 
  markup += ("<tr><td>");
  markup += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("title")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  markup += ("</td><td>");
  markup += (x[i].getElementsByTagName("description")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
  markup += ("</td></tr>");
}
markup += ("</table>")
document.write(markup);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Keep in mind, this is the RSS Channel: http://www.nacion.com/rss/deportes/
And this is the same : http://www.nacion.com/Generales/RSS/EdicionRss.aspx?section=deportes

But doesn't display anything... Any help... please...

Comment: What does your browser's JavaScript console say?

Comment: @Quentin console say this: Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 new%20%204.html:17
(anonymous function)

Comment: I don't see any CORS headers in the response when requesting that _RSS_ feed. Are you sure you're not incurring the _same-origin policy_?

Comment: @user3212973 — And what do you get if you search for `Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101` on Google?

Comment: @Quentin I searched... but... i did not see anything clear (for me...) may if you can give any clue... Im new in javascript... Thanks in advance.